# What variable is the conditional probability function a function of?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

I've got the following excerpt from my notes in my statistics course:

[image]

In the second line, the professor put $x=1$ in the Poisson distribution equation. My question, how do I know that the conditional distribution function is a function of $X_2$, and not $X_1$?

Comment: No you can't.  The conditional distribution function $X_2\mid X_1$ is by defintion a function of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會: But then how can the professor have substituted 1 into the equation, if it's not a function of $X_2$?

Comment: It's a function of both $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會: But in the second line, he substituted, $P(X_2 = x_2 | X_1 = x_1)$ with $\frac{e^{-k}k^1}{1!}$. So in the Poisson distribution, in the place of the variable $x$, he put $1$. So that means he made it a function of $X_2$, right?

Comment: In your previous comment, I don't understand what $x$ is.  $P(X_2 = x_2 | X_1 = x_1)$ is a function of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會: The probability density function for a Poisson distribution is $P(X = x) = \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^x}{x!}$. In this function, he substituted, 1, in the first term (second line)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86846/discussion-between-gnusupporter-8964--and-the-questioner).

Answer (score 1):

You are given that 
$$
P(X_2 = j | X_1 = k) =
e^{-k} \frac{k^j}{j!}
$$ for any nonnegative integers $j, k$. Now just plug in $j=1$ to obtain
$$
P(X_2 = 1 | X_1 = k) =
e^{-k} \frac{k^1}{1!}.
$$